# Can I use Sqlplus instant client without install Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have installed instant client packages (oracle, sqlplus, devel) but I can't connect because I have not Oracle Database (I read a lot of guides but I don't understand what it is really required..). I would to know what I really need to make my sqlplus instant client work. Thank you.

Comment: You need to install Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, generally speaking, you don't have to have a database installed on your computer - you can use SQL*Plus to access a database over the network (but I presume that it is not what you're after).

Oracle Technology Network provides [Download](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/index.html) section; you can download & install any version you want (for free, as long as you use it for educational purposes). As it seems that you're new in Oracle world, consider installing Oracle Express Edition (XE).

The newest version is [18c XE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)(currently, available only for Linux). Previous version, which runs on Windows as well, is [11g XE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/xe-prior-releases-5172097.html).

Installation process is simple; more or less, you'd click NEXT button several times and you'll get a working database. Do read & follow Installation Guide for more info (available in the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/index.htm) section (this link leads to 11g XE version).